# How do you find Eigenvectors for common root Eigenvalue?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I was tasked with finding the eigenvalues and eigenvectors for the matrix:

> $$A=\begin{pmatrix}
> -2&2&-3\\
> 2&1&-6\\
> -1&-2&0\\
> \end{pmatrix}$$

I had found the eigen values as $\lambda=5,-3,-3$. Now, I proceeded to find eigenvectors. For $\lambda=5$, I got the characteristic equation as:

$$A-5I=\begin{pmatrix}
-7&2&-3\\
2&-4&-6\\
-1&-2&-5\\
\end{pmatrix}$$

I used cross multiplication to get the eigen vector.

However for $\lambda=-3$, I'm facing a problem. The characteristic matrix is:

$$A+3I=\begin{pmatrix}
1&2&-3\\
2&4&-6\\
-1&-2&3\\
\end{pmatrix}$$

Here, all the equations are proportional to each other, and cross multiplication only gave me a trivial eigenvectors. How can I solve it in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we look at the matrix $A+3I$, we can see that the second and third row are multiples of the first row.

An eigenvector corresponds to eigenvalue $-3$ satisfies $$(A+3I)v=0$$

You just have to solve for all the solution to

$$v_1+2v_2-3v_3=0$$

Let $v_2=s$ and $v_3=t$, $v_1=-2s+3v_3$.

$$\begin{bmatrix} v_1 \\ v_2 \\ v_3\end{bmatrix}= s\begin{bmatrix} -2 \\ 1 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}+ t\begin{bmatrix} 3 \\ 0 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: I don't understand how you got the result from "Let $v_2=s$ and $v_3=t$, $v_1=-2s+3t$". Can you elaborate there?

Comment: The first row of the vector read $v_1 = -2s+3t$, the second line reads $v_2 = s$, the third line is $v_3=t$. I just write them in vector form.

Comment: In other words, $\begin{bmatrix}v_1\\v_2\\v_3\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}-2v_2+3v_3\\v_2\\v_3\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}-2v_2\\v_2\\0\end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}3v_3\\0\\v_3\end{bmatrix} = v_2 \begin{bmatrix}-2\\1\\0\end{bmatrix} + v_3 \begin{bmatrix}3\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: @MishaLavrov Thanks

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh Can you have a third eigenvector for eigenvalue -3 with $v_1=0$?

Comment: Sure, in fact there are infinitely many eigenvectors but we have found them all. To let $v_1=0$, let $s=1.5$ and $t=1$. The set of all the eigenvectors correponding to eigenvalue $-3$ are the solution set to the linear system $(A+3I)v=0$.